# Replacing address bar character without reloading

Tags: javascript, html, url

Any possible way to replace question mark ? With ampersand in the current page of the website address bar/location without reloading the page through Javascript?

ORIGINAL WEBSITE ADDRESS: 
http://learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582926.xhtml?tema=23&hash=c7a143a3a

NEW WEBSITE ADDRESS
http://learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582926.xhtml&tema=23&hash=c7a143a3a

Note: i wanna change ?tema to &tema

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/824349/4782937)?

Comment: Moer to the point if you have a [valid query string](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) why would you want to convert it to something that isn't a valid query string?

Comment: Yes, but dont know how to make that work with this. I would love if you can help me out with mine with the code, thanks.

Comment: It wont make it an invalid string.